# img с указанным align выпадает из родительского div'a

Tags: html, css

нужно чтобы `div` растягивался по высоте изображения. Забавы с `position` не помогают что-то

```
<div style="border:1px solid #000;">
<img src="http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png" align="right">
sometext
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<div style="border:1px solid #000;">
<img src="http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png" align="right">
sometext
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Но тут осторожнее с `clear:both` : его еще надо правильно обработать, а то дизайн может поехать.

Comment: Вот спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Это нормальное поведение, равносильно:

```
img{
    display: block;
    float: right;
}
```

Как вариант:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #000;">
    <div id="pic1"></div>
sometext
</div>

#pic1{
    background-image: url('http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
    height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: Я в курсе. Вопрос, как поэлегантней этого избежать.

Answer (score 1):

Для это требуется что бы и картинка и сам блок были, как бы это правильно сказать :), в одном потоке вот что у меня получилось:

```
<div style="border:1px solid #000;float:left;width:100%;">
        <img src="http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png" style="float:right;" align="right">
        sometext, sometext, sometext, sometext, sometext, sometext, sometext, sometext, sometext, sometext
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

то есть ты хочешь сказать что тебе нужно чтоб верхушка текста совпадала с верхом картинки? если так то там все правильно посмотри на картинку http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png там вверху много белого места из-за этого высота больше, и выходит что верх текста и картинки совпадают

Comment: @Horus Перечитайте вопрос. А потом еще раз. Пример кода приведен в общем виде.

Кстати, ответ уже получен и ответ принят.