# Как можно сделать так, чтобы элемент внутри элемента, мог выходить за его границы?

Tags: css3, html5

Здравствуйте.
Как можно сделать так, чтобы элемент внутри элемента, мог выходить за его границы. Примерно так:

[image]

Тут, синим выделен внутренний элемент. Красным - элемент, содержащий синий. Ну, надеюсь понятно. И внешний и внутренний элементы - элементы **DIV**.

**PS**
Не использовать абсолютное позиционирование (`position: absolute`)

Comment: position absolut не проходит? чисто спортивный интерес!

Comment: Не. Нельзя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну нельзя **position: absolute**, так используйте **position: relative**. [Посмотреть примерчик](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/9kQap/).

```
<div>
    <div>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
</div>
```

и

```
div {
    background: #900;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
div div {
    background: #FF0;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Для второго варианта

```
div {
    background: #900;
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: -300px;
    top: 150px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 5;
}
div div {
    background: #FF0;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    top: -150px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: Посмотрите, что получается, если пытаюсь сделать второй вариант ( http://jsfiddle.net/9kQap/1/ ). Мне надо, чтобы уходил квадрат вверх, а не вниз.

Comment: Старею я наверное )) Хоть стреляйте, но не могу понять зачем вам это надо, но вот можно поизвращаться и [таким образом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/9kQap/2/).

Comment: А как у вас это получилось?!! Не забудьте в ответ код перенести.

Comment: Как получилось? Этот вопрос меня больше в тупик поставил, чем вопрос вашего поста ))) Может потому, что веб-разработками совсем недавно занимаюсь... еще и восьми лет не прошло. Поэтому в памяти всё свежо ;)

Answer (score 1):

У меня был [обратный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/74747/img-%D1%81-%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-align-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-div-a-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82). `float` не поможет?

Comment: Не. Ни один из ответов не решил проблему. С первым вариантом проблем нет, если только он будет именно таким. Вот с реализацией второго - проблемы. Элемент уезжает вниз, а мне надо вверх.